# what's the difference between share() and publish().autoConnect()?

Tags: rx-java

According to my point of view.I think`share()` is the same with`publish().autoConnect()`.But in this code the results are not the same

```
Observable<Integer> cold = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hot Observable Emit " + i);
            subscriber.onNext(i);
        }
    });

    ConnectableObservable<Integer> connectble = cold.publish().autoConnect(2);
    //Obserable(Integer) connectavle = cold.share();
    connectble.subscribe(subscriber1);
    connectble.subscribe(subscriber2);
```

the `publish(). autoConnect() output`

```
Hot Observable Emit 0
Subscriber 1 : 0
Subscriber 2 : 0
....
```

the `share() output`

```
Hot Observable Emit 0
Subscriber 1 : 0
//the subscriber2 not receive event
```

In this case,we can not use `share()` for Multicasting in rx-java?  I find a [conclusion](https://gist.github.com/benjchristensen/e4524a308456f3c21c0b#comment-1367814) but not suitable for this case.

test environment：　oracle jdk1.8 rx-java 1.2 IDEA ubuntu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are different in that when subscribers unsubscribe from a `share`, the upstream is disconnected and when new subscribers subscribe, the upstream source is resubscribed and starts from the beginning (if cold).

`autoConnect` waits for the specified amount of subscribers, connects once and never disconnects when all subscribers unsubscribe. Here is a [description](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/10/operator-internals-autoconnect.html) about how it works.

Comment: so `share` can use for `Multicasting`.In this case, why we need `share` and `publish().RefCount()`.I am a beginner of RxJava.

Comment: You can multicast with both but `share` can resubscribe to the source if for some reason the number of subscribers goes 1 - 0 - 1.

Comment: But from my code,why subscriber2 can not receive event.if `share` can use for `Multicasting`,subscriber2 should receive event.

Comment: Sorry,I do not know Why the two results are not the same.Can you speak the reason. When new subscribers subscribe and the upstream source is resubscribed. so the subscriber2 can not receive event ?

Comment: `share` connects to your source when the first subscriber subscribes which triggers the 2 element loop synchronously and subscriber1 receives both events. Then subscriber2 subscribes but your source doesn't emit anything after that so neither subscriber1 or subscriber2 receves any further events.

Comment: @akarnokd So neither `publish` nor `share` will buffer events emitted from source then replay them to later subscriber?